# Python3: zip in range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to zip 2 lists together into 1, which I was already able to do. I've got 2 lists with several things in them, but I'm asking the user to input a number, which should determine the range.
So i've got List1: A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6 and List2: B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6
I know how to display the 2 complete lists, but what I'm trying to do is, if the user enters number "3", the zip should only display: (A1,B1), (A2,B2), (A3,B3) instead of the whole list. So here's what I tried:

```
a = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6"]
b = ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6"]
c = zip(a,b)
number = int(input("please enter number"))
for x in c:
    print(x[:number])
```

But this doesn't work. I tried to look it up, but couldn't find anything. I would be glad, if someone could help me out.

Comment: Take a look at the `enumerate` function and the `break` keyword - that will get you to where you need to be.  Alternatively, look at `itertools.islice`.

Answer (score 8):

You can slice the result of `zip()` with [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> list(islice(c, number))
[('A1', 'B1'), ('A2', 'B2'), ('A3', 'B3')]
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a `for` loop here - you only need to do the operation you're trying to do once. Also, a generator object returned by `zip` can't be "subscripted" (accessed using `[]`), so you need to convert it to a list first using `list`.

Here's some modified code that works:

```
a = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6"]
b = ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6"]
c = list(zip(a,b))
number = int(input("please enter number"))
print(c[:number])
```

Example of usage and output:

```
please enter number 3
[('A1', 'B1'), ('A2', 'B2'), ('A3', 'B3')]
```

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt, use print:

```
>>> a = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6"]
>>> b = ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6"]
>>> c = zip(a,b)
>>> number = 3
>>> for x in c:
...  print(x)
... 
('A1', 'B1')
('A2', 'B2')
('A3', 'B3')
('A4', 'B4')
('A5', 'B5')
('A6', 'B6')
```

As you can see, `x` is a pair, so `x[:number]` would only show the `number` first items of the pair.

What you actually want to do is show the `number` first pairs:

```
>>> c = list(zip(a,b))
>>> print(c[:3])
[('A1', 'B1'), ('A2', 'B2'), ('A3', 'B3')]
```

(Note that I used `list()` on the value returned by `zip()`, because `zip` objects as not subscriptable)

If you want to iterate instead of just printing them like this, it's easy:

```
>>> for x in c[:3]:
...     print(x)
... 
('A1', 'B1')
('A2', 'B2')
('A3', 'B3')
```